# how to change radiobutton size and label size in actionscript.?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, radio-button

I am trying to change my radiobutton size and label size in pure as3...

```
searchRB = new RadioButton();
    searchRB.name = "search";
    searchRB.group = rbg;
    searchRB.label="Search";
    searchRB.labelPlacement=ButtonLabelPlacement.BOTTOM;
    searchRB.selected = true;
    searchRB.move(0, (searchInput.y + searchInput.height/3) );
    searchRB.se

//Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS there any reason why this wouldn't work?

```
searchRB.width = someNewInteger;
searchRB.height = someNewInteger;
```

Comment: Something somewhere in your code could have been changing the height and width again.